# Proof by induction $3^{2n}-2^n$ is multiply of 7

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, induction, divisibility

Proof $3^{2n}-2^n$ is multiply of 7

First $n=1$, $9-2=7$

For N+1, $3^{2(n+1)}-2^{n+1}=3^{2n+2}-2^n\cdot2$=$9\cdot3^{2n}-2\cdot2^n$

Can someone give me hint how can i get multiply of 7?

Comment: How is that 3-2=7 ?

Comment: Im so sorry!! Its 3^{2n}-2^n

Comment: it should be $3^{2(n+1)}$ not $3^{2n+1}$

Comment: also you need to use the assumption of $n$-th case, to show that the ($n+1$)-st case holds; this is called the inductive step

Comment: The easiest proof is the direct one: $3^{2n}-2^n = 9^n-2^n = (9-2)(9^{n-1} + \cdots +2^{n-1})$.

Comment: $$3^{2n} - 2^n = (7 + 2)^n - 2^n$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the induction step note that assuming as hypotesis

$$3^{2{n}}- 2^{n}=7k$$

we have

$$3^{2{(n+1)}}-2^{n+1}=9\cdot3^{2{n}}-2\cdot 2^{n}=9\cdot 7k +9\cdot2^{{n}}-2\cdot 2^{n}=7(9k+2^n)$$

Comment: Thankyou so much!!!!^^

Answer (score 2):

To continue the inductive step notice that;

$9\cdot 3^{2n}-2\cdot 2^n = 9\cdot 3^{2n}-(9-7)\cdot 2^n= 9(3^{2n}-2^n)+7\cdot 2^n$ ,

which is divisible by $7$

Comment: Thankyou so much!!^^

Answer (score 1):

$3^{2(n+1)}-2^{n+1}=9\cdot 3^{2n}-2 \cdot2^n=2(3^{2n}-2^n)+7 \cdot 3^{2n}$.

Comment: Thankyou so much!!!!^^